# How to print test results in teardown using autouse fixtures in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures

I am new to pytest and I am trying to understand fixtures.
I want to print the result of my testcase (pass or fail) in teardown of the fixture.
The fixture should be use the auto use feature .

Upon running the testcase if the testcase has failed.

The print statement should say pass or fail if the test cases has failed

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Community's comment but, if all you want is to access the results of the tests in the teardown part of the fixture, it is documented: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures

(Also, your question may be a duplicate of [How to use test result in "teardown" in fixtures in "pytest" framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295803/how-to-use-test-result-in-teardown-in-fixtures-in-pytest-framework) )

Comment: I refered  to the link but I find hard to understand how get_result and hook implementation works is there a way you can simplify and explain the example. Thanks in advance